# R - Setting the class of an object created with by()

Tags: r, grouping, lapply, summarytools

First a little bit of context:

In my package [summarytools](https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools), I've defined a `print` method for objects of classs "summarytools". I have also created a function `view()` that handles objects created using `by()` or `lapply()` in such a way that the output doesn't include the lines stating the group -- or the variable in the case of `lapply()`; summarytools displays its own headings containing that information, so there is some redundancy when using `print`. Also, the main headings are not repeated when using `view()`.

Here's an example. Note that in this version (in development), I included a message advising the use of `view()`:

```
> library(summarytools)
> (tmp <- with(tobacco, by(smoker, gender, freq)))
gender: F
For best results printing list objects with summarytools, use view(x, method = 'pander')
Frequencies   
tobacco$smoker     
Type: Factor    
Group: gender = M   

              Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.
----------- ------ --------- -------------- --------- --------------
        Yes    147     30.06          30.06     30.06          30.06
         No    342     69.94         100.00     69.94         100.00
       <NA>      0                               0.00         100.00
      Total    489    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
gender: M
Frequencies   
tobacco$smoker     
Type: Factor    
Group: gender = F   

              Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.
----------- ------ --------- -------------- --------- --------------
        Yes    143     29.24          29.24     29.24          29.24
         No    346     70.76         100.00     70.76         100.00
       <NA>      0                               0.00         100.00
      Total    489    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
```

And now using `view()`:

```
> view(tmp, method = "pander")
Frequencies   
tobacco$smoker     
Type: Factor    
Group: gender = M   

              Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.
----------- ------ --------- -------------- --------- --------------
        Yes    147     30.06          30.06     30.06          30.06
         No    342     69.94         100.00     69.94         100.00
       <NA>      0                               0.00         100.00
      Total    489    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00

Group: gender = F   

              Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.
----------- ------ --------- -------------- --------- --------------
        Yes    143     29.24          29.24     29.24          29.24
         No    346     70.76         100.00     70.76         100.00
       <NA>      0                               0.00         100.00
      Total    489    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
```

I've thought about ways through which the objects of class "by" would automatically be dispatched to `view()` instead of `print()`. If I add the class "summarytools" to those objects, the `print()` method could redirect the call to `view()`, making it simpler for users to get proper, optimal outputs.

The solutions I've thought of, so far, are the following:

1. Adding a "by" argument to the functions so that I have full control on the created objects' proporties. I'm not fond of this solution, since 1) I try to rely on base R functions that people are familiar with rather than introducing new parameters, and 2) I'd still have a similar issue when objects are created with `lapply()`.
2. Redefining `by()` so that when it's called from one of summarytools' functions, it appends the desired class to the created objects. I've avoided this because I'm hesitant to redefine base functions. I'd rather not see messages to the effect that objects have been masked when the package is loaded.
3. Defining a package-specific `by()`, such as `by_st()`; I could use basically the same code as `by.default()` and `by.data.frame()`, the only difference being that I'd add the "summarytools" class to the created objects. This is a sort of compromise that I'm considering.

My question is the following: could there be other, maybe better solutions I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use S3 method for `print.by` to dispatch to your custom function:

```
old.print.by = print.by # save the original function so we can restore it later
print.by = summarytools::view # redefine print.by to dispatch to custom function
tmp
```

[image]

To restore original function later you can do `print.by = old.print.by`.

If you only want your new function to operate on lists that contain objects of class "summarytools", you can use

```
print.by = function(x, method = 'pander', ...) {
  if ("summarytools" %in% class(x[[1]])) {
    summarytools::view(x, method, ...)
  } else {
    old.print.by(x, ...)
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems very promising... So what you're saying is I could define and register `print.by()` in the package, and inside the function, check whether objects in the list are of class "summarytools", and if not, redispatch to the original `print.by()`?

Comment: exactly, I edited the answer to show how you can dispatch to the desired function, depending on class of object.  I use an `if` test for this, rather than S3, because the class of "summarytools" is buried within the objects in the list returned by `by`, rather than being a class of the top level list itself

Comment: Very nice. I just replaced the call to `old.print.by` by a call to `base::print.by`, and it works like a charm. Many thanks to you, I wasn't convinced at all that I'd find a good solution like this!